# Is there any way to read the class parametrized arg in class varaible using pytest python?

Tags: python, pytest

For example:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input', [1, 2, 3, 4])
class TestClass:
    var = test_input # like this
    def test_something1(self, test_input):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a fixture with `request` parameter and get the values from it. If you use `scope='class'` it will run once before all the tests and insert the value to `var` attribute

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('test_input', [1, 2, 3, 4])
class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture(scope='class', autouse=True)
    def get_parameters(self, request):
        TestClass.var = request.cls.pytestmark[0].args[1]

    def test_something1(self, test_input):
        print(self.var) # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```